# Find the index of an item in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

How can I find value index from `ComboBox`? I tried this but it always returns -1;

```
sexCombo.SelectedIndex = sexCombo.Items.IndexOf(teacherInfo["sex"].ToString());
```

Here how the ComboBox items are added:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="sexCombo" Margin="5,20,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="الجنس" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="45" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ذكر"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="أنثى"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: `ComboBox` has a property called `SelectedItem` which you can Bind to Look into that. It will give you the actual item that you want to use.

Comment: What did you set the ItemsSource of the ComboBox to?

Comment: @mm8 ComboBox items were added in XAML.

Comment: Post your XAML then...the type of these items certainly matters.

Comment: @mm8 I updated my qquestion with the requested XAML.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Items` collection of the `ComboBox` contains `ComboBoxItems` so you need to get the index of the corresponding `ComboBoxItem` element. Try this:

```
var comboBoxItem = sexCombo.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content.ToString() == teacherInfo["sex"].ToString());
int index = sexCombo.SelectedIndex = sexCombo.Items.IndexOf(comboBoxItem);
```

Comment: Now it works, but why I never did read that the `combobox` items are type of `ComboBoxItem`?

Comment: You can add any items you want to it but in your XAML you have added ComboBoxItems.

Comment: OK, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

To use combobox.items.indexof, you need to put String in combobox, like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Combobox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="504,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="25">
    <System:String>Item1</System:String>
    <System:String>Item2</System:String>
    <System:String>Item3</System:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Then when you use Combobox1.items.indexof("Item2") it will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it like this.

```
For i = 0 To comboBox.Items.Count - 1
    If comboBox.Items(i).ToString = "searchString" Then
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

This will make the selection of the string value you're searching for.